# ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.encode()

Tags: groovy

I am trying to encode bytes to Base64 in groovy and I am getting returned the above error when I am trying to run it.

Code Snippet:

```
 final String credentialsPair = """${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}"""
                final byte[] bytes = Base64.encode(credentialsPair.getBytes())
                final String header = "Basic " + bytes.toString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or using groovy only:

```
final String encoded = "$GIT_USERNAME:$GIT_PASSWORD".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
final String header = "Basic $encoded"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
final String credentialsPair = """${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}"""
final String encoded = Base64.encoder.encodeToString(credentialsPair.bytes)
final String header = "Basic $encoded"
```

Or you can use the Groovy method on byte[]

```
final String credentialsPair = """${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}"""
final String encoded = "${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}".bytes.encodeBase64()
final String header = "Basic $encoded"
```